# New to SQL, CREATE TABLE error

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 CREATE TABLE `ROUTE` (
  `route_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `route_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `DELIVERY_VEHICLE_veh_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `DELIVERY_DRIVER_dr_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`route_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_ROUTE_DELIVERY1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`DELIVERY_VEHICLE_veh_ID` , `DELIVERY_DRIVER_dr_ID`)
    (`VEHICLE_veh_ID` , `DRIVER_dr_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

I'm new to SQL and trying to learn by practicing. There's an error in my syntax that I don't understand. Any help/suggestions?

> (`VEHICLE_veh_ID` , `DRIVER_dr_ID`) at line 9

```
CREATE TABLE `DRIVER` (
  `dr_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `dr_title` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `dr_fname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `dr_lname` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `dr_DOB` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `dr_licenceNo` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `dr_phone` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `dr_email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dr_ID`));

CREATE TABLE `VEHICLE` (
  `veh_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `veh_reg` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `veh_make` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `veh_model` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `veh_mileage` INT NOT NULL,
  `veh_MOTdate` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `veh_servicedate` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`veh_ID`));
```

These are the other tables ROUTE is related to. I had no issues inserting DRIVER and VEHICLE tables into the DB, what's wrong with ROUTE?

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY (DELIVERY_VEHICLE_veh_ID) REFERENCES VEHICLE(veh_ID)` etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE `ROUTE` (
  `route_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `route_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `DELIVERY_VEHICLE_veh_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `DELIVERY_DRIVER_dr_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`route_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_ROUTE_VEHICLE`
    FOREIGN KEY (`DELIVERY_VEHICLE_veh_ID`)
    REFERENCES `VEHICLE`(`veh_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,

    CONSTRAINT `fk_ROUTE_DRIVER`
    FOREIGN KEY (`DELIVERY_DRIVER_dr_ID`)
    REFERENCES `DRIVER`(`dr_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there are *two* foreign keys in the `ROUTE` table.

One of them references the `DRIVER` table.

The other references the `VEHICLE` table.

Your foreign key constraint definitions should look more like this:

```
  , CONSTRAINT `fk_ROUTE_DELIVERY_DRIVER`
    FOREIGN KEY (`DELIVERY_DRIVER_dr_ID`)
      REFERENCES `DRIVER` (`dr_ID`)
      ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT

  , CONSTRAINT `fk_ROUTE_DELIVERY_VEHICLE`
    FOREIGN KEY (`DELIVERY_VEHICLE_veh_ID`)
      REFERENCES `VEHICLE` (`veh_ID`)
      ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
```